# Sleep without lock Gtk.main() in a function

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I have got a function in my gtk app. I want to wait 2 seconds in that function.
For example:

```
[...]

def do_something_and_wait(self):
    #do something here
    time.sleep(2)
    # do something more

Gtk.main()
```

If I use `time.sleep(2)` directly, Gui freezes for 2 seconds.
How can I wait 2 seconds in a function without lock `Gtk.main()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gtk.Main_iteration()` to temporarily hand control back to the GUI, see:

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gtk-functions.html#function-gtk--main-iteration
and
http://book.huihoo.com/gtk+-gnome-application-development/sec-mainloop.html

This will not sleep for *exactly* 2s, but will pause for approximately 2s and still allow the GUI to respond to other events. As bazza points out, disabling the calling widget would also be a good idea.

```
def updateGUI():
    '''Force update of GTK mainloop during a long-running process'''
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration(False)

def wait_2s():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        updateGUI()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a gtk timeout. See

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TimeoutsIOAndIdleFunctions.html

Your existing function would add the timeout instead of time.sleep(), and then return. A second function would 'do something more', and would be specified as the callback function for the timeout.

You'd probably want the first function to disable whichever GUI widget is used to set this part of your program running. This will stop the user pressing that button twice whilst you're waiting for the 2 seconds to elapse. The second function should re-enable it.